# Create dummy-variables for different factors with the same levels

Tags: r, categorical-data, r-factor

I have a dataset containing mostly categorical variables (factors) I am trying to format. 
The dataset is currently formatted like this:

```
    Obs X1 X2 X3 X4 ... X50
    1   A  B  C  D
    2   B  A  D  E
    3   B  C  D  A
```

However, A for X1 and X2 should mean the same, i.e. X1 and X2 can be thought of as what factor was detected first. My idea was to formulate the data set using dummies;

```
    Obs A B C D ...
    1   1 1 1 1 ...
    2   1 1 0 1 ...
    3   1 1 1 1 ...
```

My attempt at a solution have been: I have separated out all the categorical variables into the data.frame df, and then tried to create dummy-variables for each level of all of the factors.

```
for (i in 1:ncol(df)){
    for(level in df[,i]){
        df2[paste("", level, sep="")] = ifelse(i == level, 1, 0)
    }
}
```

However, when I try to run this code R seems to freeze - is there any reasons for why this shouldn't work? 
Does anyone have any suggestions for a more efficient way of dealing with the problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create dummy variables quickly, create a sparse matrix using the `Matrix` library. You need to convert your categorical variables to factors if they are not already using `data$X1<-as.factor(data$X1)`

```
library(Matrix)
 f <- as.formula(DependedntVar~  + X1
                  + X2
                  + X3..etc)

  # transform dataframe to spareMatrix
  x <- model.matrix(f, data)
  y <- as.matrix(DependedntVar, ncol=1)
```

Now you can model y using your sparse matrix x, where y is a one column Matrix containing your dependent variable and x is a sparse matrix where factors have been transformed into dummay variables.

Also you need to be careful of autocorrelation between X1 and X2 as it would appear from what you are saying they are 100% correlated